# How $ng^{-1}\in ng^{-1}N \implies ng^{-1}\in g^{-1}N$?

Tags: group-theory

As part of a proof inside Proposition 5, Ch. 3, in the book *Abstract Algebra* by Dummit and Foote, it says:

> Let $G$ be a group and let $N$ be any subgroup of $G$.
>
> $\dots$
>
> Since $1 \in N$, $ng^{-1}.1\in ng^{-1}N$. Thus $ng^{-1}\in g^{-1}N$.
>
> $\dots$

$1$ is the identity of the group $G$.

Why $ng^{-1}\in ng^{-1}N \implies ng^{-1}\in g^{-1}N$? And, of course $G$ is a general group not considered to be abelian.

EDIT - Here is the text (and the normal subgroups have not been introduced yet):

> **Proposition 5.** Let $G$ be a group and let $N$ be a subgroup of $G$.
>
> 1. The operation on the set of left cosets of $N$ in $G$ described by $$uN\cdot vN=(uv)N$$ is well defined if and only if $gng^{-1}\in N$ for all $g\in G$ and all $n\in N$.
> 2. If the above operation is well defined, then it makes the set of left cosets of $N$ in $G$ into a group. In particular the identity of this group is the coset $1N$ and the inverse of $gN$ is the coset $g^{-1}N$ i.e., $(gN)^{-1}=g^{-1}N$.
>
> *Proof:* 1. Assume first that this operation is well defined, that is, for all $u,v\in G$, $$\text{if }u,u_1\in uN\text{ and }v,v_1\in vN\ \ \ \ \ \ \text{ then }\ \ \ \ \ \ uvN=u_1v_1N.$$ Let $g$ be an arbitrary element of $G$ and let $n$ be an arbitrary element of $N$. Letting $u=1,u_1=n$ and $v=v_1=g^{-1}$ and applying the assumption above we deduce that $$1g^{-1}N=ng^{-1}N\ \ \ \ \ \text{i.e.,}\ \ \ \ \ \ g^{-1}N=ng^{-1}N.$$ Since $\color{red}{\displaystyle\underline{\color{black}{\displaystyle 1\in N, ng^{-1}\cdot 1\in ng^{-1}N.\text{ Thus }ng^{-1}\in g^{-1}N}}}$, hence $ng^{-1}=g^{-1}n_1,$ for some $n_1\in N$. Multiplying both sides on the left by $g$ gives $gng^{-1}=n_1\in N$, as claimed.
>
> Conversely, assume $gng^ {-1}\in N$ for all $g\in G$ and all $n\in N$. To prove the operation stated above is well defined let $u,u_1\in uN$ and $v,v_1\in vN$. We may write $$u_1=un\ \ \text{and}\ \ v_1=vm,\ \ \ \ \ \text{for some }n,m\in N.$$ We must prove that $u_1v_1\in uvN:$ $$\begin{align}u_1v_1&=(un)(vm)=u(vv^{-1})nvm\\ &=(uv)(v^{-1}nv)m=(uv)(n_1m),\end{align}$$ where $n_1=v^{-1}nv=(v^{-1})n(v^{-1})^{-1}$ is an element of $N$ by assumptions. Now $N$ is closed under products, so $n_1m\in N$. Thus $$u_1v_1=(uv)n_2,\ \ \ \  \ \ \text{for some }n_2\in N.$$ Thus the left cosets $uvN$ and $u_1v_1N$ contain the common element $u_1v_1$. By the preceding proposition they are equal. This proves that the operation is well defined.
>
> 2. If the operation on cosets is well defined the group axioms are easy to check and are induced by their validity in $G$. For example, the associative law holds because for all $u,v,w\in G$, $$\begin{align}(uN)(vNwN) &= uN(vwN) \\ &= u(vw)N \\ &= (uv)wN=(uNvN)(wN),     \end{align}$$ since $u(vw)=(uv)w$ in $G$. The identity in $G/N$ is the coset $1N$ and the inverse of $gN$ is $g^{-1}N$ as is immediate from the definition of the multiplication.

Comment: The assumption in the theorem is that coset multiplication is well-defined. The first part of the proof shows that $g^{-1}N = ng^{-1}N.$

Comment: @sqtrat - Why "well-defined" results in the mentioned inclusion? (the normal subgroups have not been introduced yet)

Comment: Do you know what well-defined means?

Comment: @sqtrat - It means that $uvN=u_1v_1N$ for any $u,u_1,v,v_1\in N$. ?

Comment: No, the operation of coset multiplication will be well-defined if for any two cosets $vN=v'N$ and $uN=uN'$, and $uvN=u'v'N$. In general this is not true. In other words, choosing different representatives of the same coset and multiplying them doesn't yield different cosets.

Comment: [Well defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-defined).

Comment: @sqtrat - I think the answer to my question in OP is in the line just before that underlined. Already, it has came to $g^{-1}N=ng^{-1}N$. I don't know why I didn't know that in mind just after one line!!

Comment: Ok, can you see that, assuming well-definedness of course, $1N=nN$ and obviously $g^{-1}N=g^{-1}N$? If so, then $g^{-1}N = 1g^{-1}N = ng^{-1}N$.

Comment: @sqtrat - Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

Is $n$ an arbitrary element of the (possibly non-normal) subgroup $N$? Then it's indeed not true, take $G = S_{3}, N = \langle (12) \rangle$, $g = (132)$, $n = (12)$.

Then $n g^{-1} = (13), n g^{-1} N = (13) N = \{ (13), (132) \}$, while $n g^{-1} \notin g^{-1} N = (123) N = \{ (123), (23) \}$.

Comment: I edited. the normal subgroups have not been introduced yet and the proof doesn't mention that either

Comment: Reread your text carefully. You have omitted **essential** information when first asking the question. The assumption is that multiplication among cosets is well defined.